# Backbone JS Collection not being populated

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Just started using backbone and all was going good until I tried load in some Json data.

```
// Category Model
var Category = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: "Not specfied",
        paramName: "not_specified",
        filter: false
    },
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Cateogory Model Initialized");
    }
});

// Category Collection
var CategoryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/assets/js/libs/items.json',
    parse: function(resp, xhr) {
        return resp.facets;
    },
    model: Category,
    initialize : function() {
        console.log('This Collection has been called');
    }
});

var categories = new CategoryList();
categories.fetch();
```

If i try to look at any of the items in the collection it is empty !

My json file looks like the following

```
 {
"facets": [
  {
"title": "Military Service & Conflict",
"searchParam": "Military"
  },  
 {
"title":"Census, land & substitutes",
"searchParam":"Census"   
 },
 {
"title":"Education & work",
"searchParam":"Education"   
}
]
}
```

If I can get this working the I just need to sort my view out

Rob

Comment: Did you try logging `resp` in the parse method and/or checking in your console what the ajax call looked like?

Comment: Keep in mind that `fetch` is an AJAX call so you won't see anything inside `categories` right away.

Comment: Modify your last line to this
var p = categories.fetch();
p.done(function() { console.log(categories.length); });

Comment: categories.fetch().done(function(){
        console.log(categories.length);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(categories));
    });

This did the trick thanks.  Whats the best approach for getting that into a view and template